# Bootstrap 3 form overlaps over using pull-right div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to set my buttons above the form, right side. The button gets placed in the right place but the form overlaps the horizontal position of the button. I'm using "< br >" to avoid that but I know it's not the best to do. How to fix that?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frm_item" name="frm_item" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="pull-right">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </div>
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ field.label }}:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                {{ field|add_class:'form-control' }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dlg_subitems" data-whatever="@mdo">Create item</button>
</form>
```

[image: This is what I get at the end]

Comment: Can you give screen shot. so that we can see how it overlaps @Ruben

Comment: why not try set your button to (position: absolute; float: right; margin-top: "10px", margin-right: "10px"; ) just change the margins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you will have to put the button inside the `form-group`

http://jsfiddle.net/1xoaw6ow/2/

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group mt-5">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.auto_id }}" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{{ field.label }}:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

try to add this css:

```
.pull-right button {
      position: absolute;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 20px;
      margin-right: 20px;
   }
```

set a free space on top of your form

```
.form-group {
    margin-top: 40px; /* change this */
}
```